# Why does the animation trigger only once?

Tags: angular, angular-animations

So, after avoiding getting my feet wet with Angular Animation, I wanted to finally try working with it. In theory, I like this a lot. But there seems to be odd behavior that doesn't seem to make sense to me.

```
    animations: [
        trigger('enterAnimation', [
          transition(':enter', [
            query(':self, td', [
              style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0 }),
              stagger(100, [
                animate(
                  '500ms',
                  style({
                    transform: 'translateX(0)',
                    opacity: 1,
                    'overflow-x': 'hidden',
                  })
                ),
              ]),
            ]),
          ]),
        ]),
    trigger('rowAnimations', [ //NOTE: I need to include this, otherwise manually added items do not work
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0 }),
        query(':self', [
          animate(
            '500ms',
            style({
              transform: 'translateX(0)',
              opacity: 1,
              'overflow-x': 'hidden',
            })
          ),
        ]),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        query(':self', [
          style({
            transform: 'translateX(0)',
            opacity: 1,
            overflow: 'hidden',
            width: '100%',
            height: '*',
          }),
          animate('500ms', style({ transform: 'translateX(50%)', opacity: 0 })),
        ]),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
```

The trigger animation `enterAnimation` works perfectly fine with preloaded data. Animation is staggered and everything with the first load of items. However, without the trigger `rowAnimations` on the :enter transition that I added and subsequently added item does not get rendered. I added the stackblitz for good measure.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-with-table-row-8qvh2f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

EDIT: Solution:

```
<table [@tableAnimations]="items.length" id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let o of items; let i = index">
    <tr class="data" [@rowAnimations]>
      <td>{{ o.Name }}</td>
      <td>{{ o.Country }}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

Just as suggested in the solution by Andrei, we want to add a trigger that goes beyond the `:enter` selector. And for that, it's simpler to bind to the array length. On its own, it's not doing much. Again, as suggested, that is being solved with the transition rule `* <=> *` which means, ANY value bound to the trigger will trigger the animation.

```
      transition('* <=> *', [
        query('@rowAnimations', [stagger(100, [animateChild()])]),
      ]),
```

And without that transition rule, the row animation isn't triggered in a staggered fashion, but all in parallel. Makes sense, in retrospect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `trigger` binding should change to trigger the `trigger`. for example
`[@enterAnimation]="items.length"`, and `transition('* <=> *'`. In your case when it enters - it is just executed once, as expected.

second: you don't really need `query(':self')`. it can be ommited

and third: you can `animateChild()` to control animation on the higher level and describe animation for the element at the element level

```
trigger('enterAnimation', [
      transition(':enter', [
        query('@rowAnimations', [
          stagger(100, [
            animateChild()
          ])
        ])
      ])
....
trigger('rowAnimations', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0 }),
          animate(
            '500ms',
            style({
              transform: 'translateX(0)',
              opacity: 1,
              'overflow-x': 'hidden',
            })
          ),
      ]),
```

this way animation is staggered at parent->:enter and then every element enter only child animation is triggering